# how to construct loop and write netmiko commands to files using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, automation, devops

As per the below script, it adds both commands to output.txt.

Instead how to add "show system" command to output1.txt and "show run" command to output2.txt.

### Python Script:

## Import program dependencies

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import getpass
```

## Read from a list of hostnames to connect to

```
hosts = open('hosts.txt','r')
hosts = hosts.read()
hosts = hosts.strip().splitlines()
```

## Get UserName and password from input

```
userName = input('Username: ')
passWord = getpass.getpass()
```

## Loop to process hosts in hosts.txt file

```
for host in hosts:
    # Define device type and connection attributes
    Brocade_ICX = {
        'device_type': 'brocade_fastiron',
        'ip': host,
        'username': userName,
        'password': passWord),
    }
    
    # Netmiko SSH Connection Handler
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**Brocade_ICX)

    #open file to write command output
    file = open('output.txt', 'w')
    
    # Execute commands
    output = net_connect.send_command('show system')
    output = net_connect.send_command('show run')
    
    # Print output to console screen
    print('-------------- Output from ' + host + '------------------')
    print(output)
    print()
    print()
    
    # Write output to file above
    file.write(output)
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

you are doing the looping wrong..

think about the last iteration of `j` variable in the loop

it points to `c` then inner loop goes through each file and and writes `c` to them

to fix it you need only one loop

```py
for i in range(len(command)):
    file = open(command[i] +'_output.txt', 'w')
    file.write(output[i])
    file.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow just four simple steps to get the solution.

1. Opening a text file.

   ```
   file = open('text file','w')
   ```
2. Adding a test line in the file.

   ```
   file.write('We will be seeing aninterated printing of numbers between 0 to 10\n')
   ```
3. Writing a `for` loop over the file.

   ```py
   for i in range(0,11): 
     file.write(str(i)) 
     file.write('\n')
   ```
4. Closing the text file.

   ```
   file.close()
   ```